# SQL Server: Specify Column Name as Attribute Using FOR XML

Tags: sql-server, space, for-xml

I need to return a column alias that has spaces in it in XML from SQL Server.  Since you can't have spaces in XML column names I'd like to return this alias in a "columnName" attribute.  Generally, the XML would need to look like this:

```
<customers>
 <customer name="Shmo, Joe">
    <over50 columnName="Number of Orders Over 50 Pounds" value="10">
    <cancelled columnName="Orders Cancelled" value="2">
 </customer>
</customers>
```

The table looks as follows:

```
|Name     |over50|cancelled
---------------------------
|Shmo, Joe|  10  |    2
```

If possible, I'd really like to use the "FOR XML" method of XML extraction.  Thanks in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.

```
SELECT Name AS [@name],
       'Number of Orders Over 50 Pounds' AS [over50/@columnName],
       over50 AS [over50/@value],
       'Orders Cancelled' AS [cancelled/@columnName],
       cancelled AS [cancelled/@value]
FROM YourTable
FOR XML PATH('customer'), ROOT('customers')
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e4c93/1)

Comment: Shazam!  That's exactly it.  Thanks a bunch Martin.